# Call tools from ArcToolBox in VBA form

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tools, vba

I am now looking for a code in VBA that can call Tools from ArcToolBox(The little red box)

I have find a Arcobject code(I thought it's can run under VBA) but it's don't work!

I have to delete the URL here....

in the end of the page it's have Arcobject code

But it's don't work!

can anyone tells me how to use it?

thanks for the help!!

@ Mike Toews

Compile error:

Sub or Function not defined

at OpenPointDataset

@artwork21 I call it from Tools>marcos>visual basic editor
It's a simple compiler in GIS not a ui control

I have tried the method with the page:

[Running a geoprocessing tool using the GPDispatch Object | ESRI Developer Network (*Wayback Machine link*)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080622051137/http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Geoprocessing/RunToolWithGPDispatch.htm)

and I try my Kriging Tool

```
Sub RunGPTool()
 'Create the Geoprocessor object
   Dim GP As Object
   Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")

  'Set the toolbox
   GP.Toolbox = "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcToolBox\Toolboxes\Spatial Analyst Tools.tbx"

   'Execute tools
  GP.Kriging "C:\sample.shp", _
    "F30", "C:\AA\456.shp", "250", "12"


 End Sub
```

but it's highlight error at
GP.Kriging "C:\sample.shp", _
"F30", "C:\AA\456.shp", "250", "12"

and says 
automation error 
unspecified error

how to fix it??

update 2011/06/11 10:00PM(+8)

@Casey

[Running a geoprocessing tool using the GPDispatch Object | ESRI Developer Network (*Wayback Machine link*)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080622051137/http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Geoprocessing/RunToolWithGPDispatch.htm)

in this page

there is no "_analysis"in the sample code...

and I tried GP.Kriging_sa

but it's still don't work....

thanks for you support!

by the way I have tried buffer it's works!!

Comment: Elaborate on *how* it does not work, e.g. error messages, etc.

Comment: how are you calling the code, from a UI Control or macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is sample code from ESRI on one method to run a Toolbox tool from VBA:
[Running a geoprocessing tool using the GPDispatch Object | ESRI Developer Network (Wayback Machine link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080622051137/http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Geoprocessing/RunToolWithGPDispatch.htm)

In my experience it's a lot easier to call the Toolbox Tools from the command line or python (scripting). The help page for each tool contains code samples for both of these methods, for example: https://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=intersect_%28analysis%29

UPDATE 6/10/11

It looks like the ESRI code sample doesn't work as is (go figure). You need to comment out the gp.Toolbox line and add the name of the toolbox to the references of the tools. For example, to fix the sample code:

```
    Sub RunGPTool()
     'Create the Geoprocessor object
       Dim GP As Object
       
       Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
  
       'Set the toolbox --COMMENT OUT THE GP.Toolbox LINE
       'GP.Toolbox = "D:\ArcGIS\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Analysis Tools.tbx"
  
       'Execute tools --APPEND THE NAME OF THE TOOLBOX TO THE TOOL
       GP.Clip_analysis "D:\Workspace\Portland.mdb\Region\streets", _
       "D:\Workspace\Portland.mdb\Region\downtown", "D:\Workspace\Portland.mdb\Region\dt_streets"
  
       GP.Buffer_analysis "D:\Workspace\Portland.mdb\Region\dt_streets", _
    "D:\Workspace\Portland.mdb\Region\dt_streetsbuf", "500"
     End Sub
```

Here is what I tested on my machine (I don't have Spatial Analysis to test your code):

```
    Sub RunGPTool()

       'Create the Geoprocessor object
        Dim GP As Object
        Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
  
       'Set the toolbox
       'GP.Toolbox = "D:\ArcGIS\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Analysis Tools.tbx"
  
       'Execute tools
       GP.MakeFeatureLayer_management "C:\Temp\NKCDC.shp", "temp_NKCDC"
  
    End Sub
```

You would change

```
 `GP.Kriging`
```

to

```
 `GP.Kriging_sa`
```