# Visual Basic call tools from ArcGIS Toolbox for Geoprocessing Conversion Tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, toolbox

I am using an updated MS Access database which has an historical legacy for data input in an organisation (there is still historical information to input) I am working for. the database calls a conversion tool from the ArcGIS Toolbox for Geoprocessing. However, this code does not appear to be working. Have seen the following article, although no solution here (see additional PDF attached is there a solution here?):

[Call tools from ArcToolBox in VBA form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/call-tools-from-arctoolbox-in-vba-form)

Below is the VB code (see attached document as well):

```
Private Sub Label38_Click()
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
' OGW All Projects export
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


' Create the Geoprocessor object
Set gp = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch.1")

' Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolBox\toolboxes\Conversion Tools.tbx"

' Script arguments...
'OGWReporting_mdb = Arguments.Item(0)
'if OGWReporting_mdb = "#" Then
OGWReporting_mdb = "I:\Database\OGW_Database\OGW_Reporting\AllOGWReporting.accdb" ' provide a default value if unspecified
'End If

' Local variables...
GWLAP_Funded_Works_lyr = "I:\Database\OGW_Database\OGW_Layers\Archives\All Works.lyr"
GWLAP_Funded_Fence_Lines_lyr__2_ = "I:\Database\OGW_Database\OGW_Layers\Archives\All Fence Lines.lyr"
Derived_Geodatabase = "I:\Database\OGW_Database\OGW_Reporting\AllOGWReporting.accdb"

' Process: Feature Class to Geodatabase (multiple)...
gp.FeatureClassToGeodatabase.tool "'I:\Database\OGW_Database\OGW_Layers\Archives\All Works.lyr';'I:\Database\OGW_Database\OGW_Layers\Archives\All Fence Lines.lyr'", OGWReporting.accdb
'MsgBox "Complete"

'End ESRI Model
```

Have updated the code to reflect the most recent versions of MS Access and ArcGIS.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap?  Also, you say it isn't working, what exactly is the issue?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error and what is the traceback.  Are you getting unexpected results?  If so, what are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: Thank you, good questions. Some further information below:

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop Pro 3.0.3. Am receiving run-time error 429 ActiveX component can't create object. When running the debug the following line of code is highlighted:                         Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")

Comment: Are you using Desktop or Pro? Their APIs are **completely** different. If you're using desktop have you activated your license? (refer LicenseInitializer class https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//004800000108000000)

Comment: If you're having trouble with the old way to create and use a geoprocessor have a look at the IGeoProcessor2 interface https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componentHelp/index.html#//002n000000tq000000 however I don't think that will help if your version truly is 3.0.3, ArcGIS desktop started at version 8, prior to that it was ArcINFO Workstation.

Comment: Hi Michael, Am using ArcGIS Pro. Am working through the information you sent through now. Really appreciate your advice. Will let you know how it goes. thanks, Davina

Comment: Have just looked into the ArcGIS Pro information on Tools that are not available in ArcGIS Pro this includes Geodatabase - the Copy Runtime Geodatabase to File Geodatabase tool has been replaced by the Mobile Geodatabase To File Geodatabase tool - would this be the problem with the code? (see link below) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm

Comment: Hi Michael, can you give any advice on structuring the code in the IGeoProcessor2 this is new to me. Thanks Davina